# Is it necessary to practice rituals to attain God?

Tags: rituals, practice, superstitions

I strongly believe in God, and I pray and thank him from the deepest of my heart for this life and all good things he has done to me. Isn't it enough to attain him ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66979/discussion-on-question-by-anurag-singh-sisodiya-is-it-necessary-to-practice-ritu).

Comment: @Pandya The chat doesn't open....is the URL wrong? Can you fix it?

Comment: @sv. Done. The room was automatically deleted for inactivity. I've undeleted.

Answer (score 1):

No rituals are needed to attain God. What is required in a pure heart and yearning. But that does not mean that all rites should be abandoned. In the *Gita*, Krishna says (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> 11.53 Neither by the Vedas, nor by penances, nor by alms-giving, nor yet by sacrifice, am I to be seen in the form in which you have now beheld Me.
>
> 11.54 But by devotion to Me alone may I be known in this form, O Arjuna, realized truly, and entered into, O dreaded prince.
>
> 11.55 He who does My work and looks on Me as the Supreme Goal, who is devoted to Me, who is without attachment and without hatred for any creature--he comes to Me, O Pandava.

and further:

> 18.3 Some philosophers declare that all works should be relinquished as evil; others say that works of sacrifice, gift, and austerity should not be given up.
>
> 18.4 Learn from Me, O best of the Bharatas, the truth about relinquishment; for relinquishment is declared to be of three kinds, O tiger among men.
>
> 18.5 Acts of sacrifice, gift, and austerity must not be given up, but should be performed. For verily, sacrifice, gift, and austerity purify the wise.
>
> 18.6 Even those works, however, should be done without attachment and desire for fruit. This, O Partha, is My conclusive and final judgement.
>
> 18.7 The renunciation of obligatory action [such as daily rites] is not proper. Its abandonment, from delusion, is declared to be of the nature of tamas.
>
> 18.9 When a man performs an obligatory action only because it ought to be done, and renounces all attachment and the fruit--his renunciation, O Arjuna, is characterized by sattva.

And the *Mundaka Upanishad* (III.ii.3.) says:

> This Atman is not to be attained by the study of the Vedas, nor by the highest intellect, nor by much learning. Whom the Atman seeks, unto him He discloses His glory.

And whom does the Atman seek? The ones that yearn for Him by purifying their hearts by *Gita* 11.55 and 18.9 above.

The doing of rituals is not needed for the attainment of God, but should not be given upon necessarily; the fruits of those rituals and non-attachment to them is what is to be given up. The Lord sees our hearts, not our actions.